# How to upload multiple files in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload

Im looking for a way to upload multiple files to this little application i found on the interwebs, http://techslides.com/demos/d3/convert-svg-png.html Its a clientside application for converting svg files to png.
so basically my question is; Is there an easy way to implement a feature to select multiple files and queue them up so they get converted one by one. Btw im pretty much a total noob.

thanks in advance:)

Comment: haver you tried <input type="file" multiple /> ?

Comment: What Ricardo said and then check out FileList API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know how i could implement that, is it as easy as changing a few lines or does it require more?

Comment: @audrey4061 On my phone currently, but you'd have to use JavaScript to process multiple images. You said it's a client side application, so you're not actually uploading anything, right? Use $('#fileInput').files to get the array of chosen files. You can then read each file in a loop using the FileReader API. I recommend you check out HTML5Rocks: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: thank you i'll look into it!